# Script Error when trying to login Team Foundation Server in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 that is working fine except for one issue. Whenever I try to connect through the sign in Wizard to Team Foundation Server I get an error in a popup Titled: "Script Error" as if it can't render the result or something. here are more info on the subject

```
Line: 4
Char: 16405
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method
code: 0
URL: https://....../TFS/Loader.min.js
```

Any suggestions? (I tried re-installing but the same issue shows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue.  I generally use Chrome, the version of MSIE installed was IE 8.  When i updated to IE 11 the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 3):

As I'm using Windows Server 2008, I couldn't find a way to reinstall IE (only to enable/disable it), so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28187268/578319) solution didn't work for me. But there is other workaround I found. When you try to connect to tfs server and the browser window "Sign in to TFS" inside Visual Studio opens with javascript error and then nothing happens, right click on the window and select "Properties" find Addres (URL) and copy full path (https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_signin?realm=...). Paste this to Internet Expolorer (doesn't work with other browsers) and sign in to tfs and you'll be redirected to some tfs web service. After this switch back to Visual Studio and try to connect to tfs again. This time you should connect without need to log in.

Answer (score 1):

I only needed to set IE as my default browser and it corrected the issue for me.

Comment: In my case IE version 8 was the problem.

Comment: Yeah I would have tried to do the upgrade to IE11 but I work in a large corporation that has the network really locked down and they specify the version we have to use corporate wide. 

I agree an upgrade would be the best solution nut in case anyone else is in the same situation as me maybe what I posted above would help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!!!! I found sol'n

Un-install IE using control panel.
Install it again and make IE default browser with recommened settings.

and you done.

Worked for my case

Comment: I read about IE could be the prob, thnx for confirming. Will check it out and mark as answered accordingly. Thank you for letting me know

Comment: Maybe it will work for others. In my case the update solved the problem. Disabling and enabling IE same version did not do much good (from program features) i did not uninstall it though

Answer (score 0):

Update to to IE 11 and everything will work fine.

Comment: I took ken's answer since his respond was first. I neutralized the downvote. appreciate you spending time to answer the question

Answer (score -1):

Update of IE is not an option for me. I need it for testing on this machine. In my case following helped me:

I opened developer tools of IE8 (press F12). It was in 'IE8 Compat View' mode. I switched to 'IE8' mode and specified Document mode to 'IE8 Standards'.

Then I were able to sign in to TFS through IE8. Once I signed in using browser I restarted Visual Studio and everything worked correctly.